# how to search for unique elements by the first column of a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a way how to create a new array from a multidimensional array by taking only elements that are unique in the first column, for example if I have an array

```
[[1,2,3],
[1,2,3],
[5,2,3]]
```

After the operation I would like to get this output

```
[[1,2,3],
[5,2,3]]
```

Obviously the second an third columns do not need to be unique.

Thanks

Comment: What about if you had  `[[1,4,3], [1,2,3],[5,2,3]]`?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are looking to keep the **first row** of **first column uniqueness**, you can just use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional `return_index` argument which will give you the first occurring index (thus fulfils the first row criteria) among the uniqueness on `A[:,0]` elements, where `A` is the input array. Thus, we would have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
_,idx = np.unique(A[:,0],return_index=True)
out = A[idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: A
Out[16]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 3]])

In [17]: _,idx = np.unique(A[:,0],return_index=True)
    ...: out = A[idx]
    ...: 

In [18]: out
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5], [3, 6, 5]]
used = []
new = [[sub, used.append(sub[0])][0] for sub in main if sub[0] not in used]
print(new)
# Output: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 6, 5]]
```